# Handling a 1/0 value with a React toggle switch and passing data back to the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, boolean

I am working to create a React update form and I'm having issues with a value I am being passes.  Currently the API I was given it supplying me a 1/0 value rather than an true/false boolean.  I was told it was because the DB uses Oracle, which does not currently support a boolean.  I was able to create a state variable called *curValue* to take the 1/0 value and make it a true/false in order to check/uncheck the toggle switch, but my problem is passing a value back to the DB.  If If use the toggle switch, it is going to pass back a true/false value rather than a 1/0 value.  Can someone please help me figure out how to use this toggle switch with a 1/0 value and get it to set the correct datatype back to the DB??

**DepartmentEdit.tsx**

```
export function DepartmentEdit(props) {
    const { closeModal, refreshTable, selectedRecord, ltUpdateUrl } = props;
    const curValue = values.isArchived === 1 ? false : true; 

    const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
        const temp = { ...errors };
        if ('name' in fieldValues)
            { temp.name = fieldValues.name ? '' : 'Department Name is required.'; }
        if ('description' in fieldValues)
            { temp.description = fieldValues.description ? '' : 'Description is required.'; }
        setErrors({
            ...temp
        });
        if (fieldValues === values)
            { return Object.values(temp).every(x => x === ''); }
    };

    const {
        errors,
        setErrors,
        handleInputChange,
        values,
        setValues,
    } = FormFunctions(true, validate);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedRecord !== null)
            {setValues({
                ...selectedRecord
        }); }
    }, [selectedRecord, setValues]);


// Edit Record
    async function editRecord(values: any) {
      if (values === values.isArchived) { values = values === true ? 1 : 
      await axios.put(`${ltUpdateUrl + (values.id)}`, values)
      .then(res => console.log( res.data))
      .catch(error => {console.log( 'the error has occured: ' + error); })
      ;
    refreshTable();
    }
// handle form submission
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if (validate()){
          editRecord(values);
          closeModal();
        }
    };

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
         <Grid item md={8}>
             <Input
                 type='text'
                 onChange={handleInputChange}
                 label='Department Name'
                 name='name'
                 value={values.name !== null ? values.name : ''}
                 error={errors.name}
            />
         </Grid>
         <Grid item md={4}>
             <ToggleSwitch
                 label1='Inactive'
                 label2='Active'
                 curValue={curValue}
                 value={values.isArchived}
             />
          </Grid>
          <Grid>
             <Button
                 type='submit'
                 text='Submit'
                 onClick={editRecord}
             />
             <Button
                 text='Cancel'
                 color='default'
                 onClick={closeModal}
             />
          </Grid>
      </Form>
    );
}
```

**ToggleSwitch.tsx**

```
export default function ToggleSwitch(props) {
  const { label1, label2, curValue, value} = props;
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(curValue);
  }, [curValue]); // re-renders the toggle switch with every change to checked value

  const handleSwitch = e => {
       setChecked(e.target.checked);
  };


  return (
    <Box className={classes.toggleSwitch}>
      <Typography>
        {label1}
        {<Switch 
          checked={checked}
          onChange={handleSwitch}
          color='primary'
          inputProps={{'aria-label': 'switch'}}
          value={value}
          />}
        {label2}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

**FormFunctions.tsx**

```
export function FormFunctions(initialValues, validateOnChange = false, validate) {
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState({} as any);
    const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({} as any);

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        });
        if (validateOnChange)
          { validate({ [name]: value }); }
    };

    const resetForm = () => {
      setValues(initialValues);
      setErrors({});
    };
    return {errors, handleInputChange, resetForm, setErrors, setValues, values};
}

export function Form(props) {
    const classes = useFormStyles();
    const { children, ...other } = props;
    return (
        <form className={classes.root} autoComplete='off' {...other}>
            {props.children}
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why is this outside of a hook? `const curValue = values.isArchived === 1 ? false : true;` Also, `values` appears to not be in scope.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl this is what has been working so far.  Just using curValue to as something to pass to the checked property.  just using the values spread operator to grab each value during the onChange.  I am pretty new to this, so  this is what I could figure out.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is handle this special case in the edit record section, since that is where the value needs to be different.

Something like this:

```
// Edit Record
  async function editRecord(values: any) {
      // here add validation that will change the value from bool to 1/0
      if(values.id === isArchived) {
        values = values === true ? 1 : 0
      }

      await axios.put(`${ltUpdateUrl + (values.id)}`, values)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(error => {console.log( 'the error has occured: ' + error); })
      ;
    refreshTable();
  }
```

Comment: @MichaelWagner  I attempted to use your solution (which seemed like a great idea), but was and error saying isArchived was not found during the if statement, so attempted to re-write it to remove the error, and I can't seem to get it to work. I updated my code with what I have tried.  the value of isArchived won't update.